# jqGrid tree auto-load messed up

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, tree, loading, treegrid

For users like me with *not so fast* connection, expanding a node while another is still loading messes up the tree. Is there a way to disable the grid while it's still loading? I'm using the latest version (4.1.1)

To replicate, go to http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> New in version 3.4 -> Tree Grid Adjacency model and click the expand buttons one after the other in a fast succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [loadui:'block'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) jqGrid option.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! I missed that one out :). too bad I can't vote up >.<

Comment: oh O_O. I thought you have to vote up to accept the answer xD. there you go.